# Currently have a many-to-many relationship, but now need to group one of the entities

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a case where there are representatives that are responsible for certain clients. They can be responsible for many clients, and those clients can have many reps. I have the tables `reps`, `clients`, and the join table of `client_reps`.

It's common in our company to have multiple reps be considered as a group. So they even have a name for the group and their own group email address. How would I even begin to properly introduce a group concept into this existing structure?

To give an example, we have reps with IDs `1`, `2`, and `3`. And then a client with ID `1`. All those reps have their own names and email addresses with their accounts. But now they want to be grouped under a single entity, with their own name and email. Instead of assigning those three individual reps, they would be assigned as a single group. The system also has to know that this group consists of those three reps for reporting purposes.

It might even be acceptable to still assign those reps individually, but as long as the system can distinguish that those three are part of a particular group.

Comment: Is the company a client? Or is it another entity that belongs to your database?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Company/client is the same thing. It's just one entity in the system. I've edited the question.

Comment: Your question doesnt describe some issues. Can a `rep_person` be part of different groups or only one, and can a client have rep from different groups or only one? and can all the members of one group handle the client or maybe only a few?

Comment: A rep can be part of 0 or many groups. Realistically, anytime a client has more than one rep, it should be considered a group from the business rules. There isn't a case where there is a group of reps, plus one individual for a given client. All the reps can handle the client they are assigned to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are talking about behaves like distribution groups.  Here is an EER diagram of how you can solve this.

[image: EER Diagram]

Reps can belong to many groups and a group may have many reps.  Each group has it's own id, name and email.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make a diagram. I understand what you're showing. Going back to my original example where there are three reps assigned to a client, the `client_reps` table would have three records, tying each of those reps to the client. If those three reps also happen to be part of a group, as recorded in the `groups_has_reps` table, how would I be able to properly query that or find that out? So for example, in the end, when contacting the reps, if there is no group set up, I would take all three of their emails. If a group exists with those three, I would use the group email.

Comment: I can't think of a query to solve that, but what you should do is (1) get all reps associated to the client, (2) get all groups associated to the reps of the client (3) check for the group whose members are the client's reps. (4) if no groups found, send to every rep, else send to group.  Consider that the reps may be a smaller subset of other group so you must get the group in where the set formed by the reps is the biggest subset.

Comment: Cool, no problem. Thanks for your help.